# Displaying document from MVC by calling method from WCF service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, serialization, document, filestreamresult

I want to display document for specified Document Id. For this, I am calling WCF service from MVC project.

In MVC project,
in HomeController.cs

```
FileStreamResult objFileStreamResult = (FileStreamResult)objDocumentServiceClient.RetrieveDocument(DocId);
```

In WCF Service project,
in DocumentService.svc.cs

```
public FileStreamResult RetrieveDocument(int DocumentID)
```

Error:

Type 'System.Web.Mvc.FileStreamResult' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute. ÿIf the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute.

Could anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Like the exception says: you can't serialize a FileStreamResult. Use som other class for transmitting your data between the WCF and MVC-backend. Then you can use FIleStreamResult to get the document to the browser.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Did as you had suggested.

Comment: For anyone stumbling on this: you can return a `Stream` object via WCF, then create the `FileStreamResult` from that in your Controller